# Force height & vertical scroll on chat widget

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I have this chat widget:

[image]

As you may notice from above, it goes infinitely long. Is there a way to enforce fixed height say 150px with scrollbars? I know to do this I need to get the `min-height`, `height` & `overflow: auto` but somehow that has to effect.

So I am wondering, what am I missing?

**Jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/eBCkT/2/

Comment: I don't know what to say. please read this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I add

```
#chat {
    height: 150px;
}
```

the chat is only 150px high and has a vertical scrollbar. You can do the same for #twitter

You can also set it for the conversation only so that the input is always visible:

```
#chat ul.chat-box {
    height: 150px; /* in this case #chat should be 150px + height of input area */
    overflow: auto;
}
```